# Transparent status bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I just started using flutter and android studio and I was wondering if there’s a way to make a transparent status bar like the pic on Android (no transition from the status bar to the appBar). When I try to set the status bar color, it gets a different shade than the appBar.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 58):

You can use the `AnnotatedRegion` widget with `SystemUiOverlayStyle` to change the chrome styles.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(...),
    );
  }
}
```

You can read more about what's possible with SystemUiOverlayStyle [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html).

Answer (score 43):

Yes, this is possible *on Android*.

In order to do that, you can use [`SystemChrome`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome-class.html). That class provides a [`setSystemUIOverlayStyle`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html) method and you can use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

Keep in mind that this will only work for Android versions equal to or greater than `Android M` and that you will need to draw below the status bar by avoiding the padding that a `Scaffold` adds automatically. You can do that by using:

```
...body: SafeArea(top: false, child: ...
```

Answer (score 31):

You can also do it app widely before you run the app in the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // transparent status bar
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 27):

#### Recommended (with Flutter 2.0)

Don't use `AnnotatedRegion` as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/systemOverlayStyle.html)

> Apps should not enclose an AppBar with their own AnnotatedRegion.

The preferred way is to use `systemOverlayStyle` property:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
  ),
)
```

Comment: `backwardsCompatibility' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is obsolete and is false by default. This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.

App developers are encouraged to opt into the new features by leaving it default (false) and using the `foregroundColor` and `systemOverlayStyle` properties as needed.

Comment: @Ugo Thanks for pointing that out, it was going to be deprecated. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 13):

@sander-dalby-larsen solution works perfectly, however, the status bar icon color becomes an issue. Following solution makes status bar `transparent` and status bar icons and navigation bar color as `black`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // transparent status bar
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, // navigation bar color
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // status bar icons' color
          systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //navigation bar icons' color
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: _getBody(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This fixes one problem and produces another one. If you navigate to another screen and come back, it again reverts back. So status bar is transparent but status bar icons are again white.

Comment: This is a  better solution, especially if you return a StreamProvicer in main.dart

Comment: @FaizanMubasher did you find any solution for the issue with back navigation?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for  solution for the same and I found a way to do this
[transparent statusbar icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOan5.png)
Inside your `Widget build(BuildContext context){  }` just add below lines,,

While using dark theme, it will make statusbar like transparent and icons to white

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light));
```

and the same goes for light theme

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));
```

I am not sure if you are looking for this or something different but this works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 3):

This will help to make your status bar transparent

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // dark text for status bar
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just do padding around the Scafold body parameter.

```
Scaffold(
         body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top), //this
            child: Widget
        )
```

if your scaffold has appBar

```
Scaffold(        
      appBar: AppBar(
                brightness: Brightness.dark, //this
      body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
      child: Widget
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do it is to import services.dart and use SystemUIOverlayStyle:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(NameOfYourApp());
}
```