# Shadow from notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have made

```
appbar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
elevation: 0
),
```

Still I'm getting this

[image: Notification shadow]

How to get that seamless transition between the Scaffold and the notification center?

Comment: Have you tried removing `primarySwatch` on your main.dart file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you want your application to use transparent statusbar. [Transparent status bar in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211640/transparent-status-bar-in-flutter)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
    );
  }
```